# Can I print only the "simple markup" in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

It seems like there is only an option to print all markup or print no markup in Microsoft Word (2010), even if only "show simple markup" is selected in the document itself.  Is there a way to print the document with only the "simple markup" (insertions/deletions), or with only the comments?

Answer (score 6):

Click the dialog launcher button in the Tracking group on the Review tab. Click the Advanced Options button. In the dialog box, specify "(none)" for "Insertions" and "Hidden" for "Deletions." Click OK twice.